# Vim - Sort Nested Blocks of SCSS

Tags: vim, sorting

## Note:

**Can someone with 300 reputation please add the tag, "scss" to this question? I'd be very appreciative.**

---

**My code (scss):**

```
.cinderblock {
    @include minwidth();
    background-image:url("images/cinderblock.jpg");
    background-position:top center;
    background-color:#b79966;
    height:528px;

    .wrapper {
        background-image:url("images/home-decorito.jpg");
        height:488px;
    }
    .big-yellow-button {
        width: auto;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:84px;
    }
}
```

**What I need it to look like:**

```
.cinderblock {
    @include minwidth();
    background-color:#b79966;
    background-image:url("images/cinderblock.jpg");
    background-position:top center;
    height:528px;

    .big-yellow-button {
        bottom:84px;
        position:absolute;
        width: auto;
    }
    .wrapper {
        background-image:url("images/home-decorito.jpg");
        height:488px;
    }
}
```

### The solution must:

- Alphabetically sort the

  - properties of the parent block
  - properties of the child blocks
  - child blocks
- Preserve indentation
- **Bonus:** Correct inconsistency in whitespace (e.g. spaces between property names and values)

Comment: If we leave the technical aspect of your question aside, this is not a very good idea. Selectors should be grouped by position on the page/in the site, cascading order, semantics… alphabetical sorting is probably worse than no order at all.

Comment: Actually, the best way to architect css is by specificity, especially when you're working on large sites like I do. Check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-BX4N8egEc

Comment: Hmm, that's what I meant with "cascading oder". Alphabetical order sucks, anyway.

Comment: Sorting properties and child selectors alphabetically is not a bad idea at all, as it cascades just fine and doesn't affect specificity. Please stay on topic.

Comment: It affects readability and comprehension which should be the primary concern when talking about sorting text/code. `width: 23px;` and `height: 46px;` are conceptually related and thus should stay together, same thing for `margin` and `padding` or `position`, `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`.

Comment: If that's your cup of tea, then cool. Personally, I prefer alphabetical because if I'm looking for a specific property amongst a long list of declarations, I know where to look that much more quickly. When you work with large amounts of CSS/SCSS, it becomes a waste of time to manually organize properties (hence, my wish to automate) as they do not affect specificity. I'd much rather be using that time to manually organize selector order.

Comment: OK, to each his/her own. I really heavily on search for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy/builtin way to do what you want. You'll obviously use the `:sort` command at one time or another but you'll need to come up with a couple of macros. Basically, the idea is to:

1. put all your rules inline

   ```
   v%
   J
   (repeat)
   ```
2. sort your selectors

   ```
   (select the inlined selectors)
   :'<,'>sort
   ```
3. expand your blocks of rules and make it look good

   ```
   :s/\[{;\]/&\r
   =%
   ```
4. sort each block

   ```
   (select the rules)
   :'<,'>sort
   ```

You can find some inspiration [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687191/how-to-make-vim-alphabetically-sort-css-rules-within-a-single-line/10688171#10688171).

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna try this out soon

Comment: I get punked on Step 2. I selected the inline selectors and punched in my sort, but they're still in the same order. Are you saying I need to sort the properties?

Comment: at step 2 you should have only lines that start with selectors like `.wrapper {...}` or `.big-yellow-button {...}`. You should be able to sort all those lines by selecting them and do `:sort` without affecting what's between the curly brackets.

Comment: Ooh, you meant that I have to v%J each inline block individually. I see. Now I'm getting a "Pattern not found" error on Step 3.

Comment: See the linked question for a more accurate pattern.

Comment: I can't make a pattern that works. This is where I need help.

Comment: What pattern did you try?

Comment: Many, but they all failed. I'm not familiar enough with magic to know what to write.

Comment: But you can't expect us to do *all* the work. Tell us what you did and we will pick up from that.

Comment: The patterns in the linked answer work.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear. I can see those patterns do work. However, I need the magic to also preserve indentation and/or autoindent.

Comment: Ah! That brand of magic will be hard to come up with. I'd suggest you simply do `=` to re-indent correctly.

Comment: It appears my newly-installed flavor of vim gets thrown off when attempting to `=` nested blocks in SCSS.